# Why are displaying and binding reference fields so hard in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In rails, its common to use code like this to do 100% of the work required for creating an edit form that contains a drop down list to a reference field for a foriegn key property:

```
<%= f.input :section, :as => :radio %>
```

I'm trying to learn asp.net mvc and while there is a lot I love, its taking me forever to figure out how to create a drop down list for a field that relates to a different model.

1) based on everyones advice, I'm going with the ViewModel pattern, and adding a property to that that is an

`IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

2) populate the select list item with values.  (why doesn't this just default to all??)

3) @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategories, Model.CategoryChoices)

4) Now, in my create/edit method on the controller, I have to read these values and save them?

I feel like I must be missing something.  All of the steps dont really bother me too much except for 4.  There is no automatic binding?  (If there is, my code doens't work because the value are always empty when I try...)

Edit: A lot of the tutorials I tried seem to reference setting the "ForeignModelNameID" field (as in, ProductID field), but my model only has the virtual Product field.  Not sure if this affected my ability to automatically bind to it or not....

I also dont really understand the purpose of the Bind="Field1,Field2,Field3" in the Edit method parameters.  Can I pass foriegn key fields to that?  Do I need to incldue the name of the key or just the name of the navigation property?

Comment: What do you mean _"why doesn't this just default to all?"_. Do you mean you expect to have all options selected? If so then set the value of `SelectedCategories` to an array of values that match the values of all the options (that's how model binding works - it binds to your properties, so if `SelectedCategories = new int[]{1,3,6}` and your options have value attributes 1 - 10, then the 1st, 3rd and 6th options will be selected.

Comment: Let's say I have product and category models.   A product has a category.  Shouldn't the select list default to all categories?   Also, when I post to the edit action, is the category supposed to bind atuomatically?   I could not get it to save automatically...  I tried adding both "category" and "categoryid" to the bind parameter list in the method signature...   Neither seemed to work.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by _Shouldn't the select list default to all categories_? A `<select multple>` posts back an array of simple values. If `categoryId` is typeof `int` then the property you bind to needs to be `public int[] SelectedCategories { get; set; }` and `CategoryChoices` needs to be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`